# Popup and ion-nav-view don't work togehter

Tags: angularjs, cordova, popup, ionic-framework

I have newbie question.

I need some really basic AngularJS in my app. I made my popup work and then added ion-nav-view. Both elements works, but not simultaneously. Now ion-nav-view works perfect, but when i change

```
body ng-app="starter"
```

to

```
body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="PopupCtrl"
```

app turns into blank site.

It must be some small mistake but i can't find, where it is. Can anyone help me? My app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
  .controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
    $scope.showAlert = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Alert',
        template: 'Alert text'
      });
    };
  });

  angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('list', {
        url: '/1',
        templateUrl: 'list.html'
      })
      .state('info', {
        url: '/2',
        templateUrl: 'info.html'
      })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/1");
  })
```

EDIT:

Body section of index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="PopupCtrl">

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="list.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="title">
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-locate" ng-click="showAlert()"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>

      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
          <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
            <img src="cover.jpg">
            <h2>Pretty Hate Machine</h2>
            <p>Nine Inch Nails</p>
          </a>
          <a class="item" ui-sref="info">
            <p>Żeby uzyskać pomoc, dotknij to pole.</p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="info.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="Informacje">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <img src="img/logo.png" style="width: 100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>


</body>
```

Comment: add your templates to question.

Comment: you need to call `$scope.showAlert()` so that alert will get shown

Comment: @PankajParkar Problem is that my app turns into totally blank, when i add `ng-controller="PopupCtrl"` to body. Calling anything is impossible.

Comment: @user293761 you need to add `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` inside your body..so that `$stateProvider` will load the template in it.

Comment: @mudasserajaz I've addet it to question

Comment: @PankajParkar `ion-nav-view` is allready in body (look at editet question). It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module should be get injected with dependency while you are creating it like here you did `angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])` but while consuming it you need to use `angular.module('starter')`, As module is already created. If you do the same thing again then previously registered component of that module will get flushed.

Like in your code you need to use `angular.module('starter')` while defining `controller` & `config`

**Code**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

    //code here

})

angular.module('starter')//<-- change here
  .controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {

    //code here

  });

  angular.module('starter') //<-- change here
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    //code here

  })
```

Comment: @user293761 Glad to help you..Thanks :)